Прослушать websocket сервера, находящегося в другой подсети
Есть некий сервер, расположенный в другой подсети по следующему адресу ws://192.168.48.33:9090/ws/uplink/app,
который посылает данные телеметрии по websocket. Как реализовать прослушку сервера на FastAPI?
Написал следующий код, но прослушка только на локальной машине ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws.
main.py
import ...

@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    while True:
        data = await websocket.receive_text()
        print(data) 


import uvicorn
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket
import asyncio
import websockets



def create_websocket_client_task(app_state):
    """
    Establish a WebSocket client connection and handle incoming messages in a loop.
    """

    async def websocket_client():
        uri = "ws://localhost:5000/ws"  # Replace with your WebSocket server URI
        try:
            async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
                print(f"Connected to WebSocket server at {uri}")

                while app_state["running"]:
                    try:
                        message = await websocket.recv()  # Receive a message
                        print(f"Received message: {message}")
                        # Process the message as needed
                    except websockets.ConnectionClosed:
                        print("WebSocket connection closed")
                        break
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in WebSocket connection: {e}")

    return websocket_client


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    app_state = {"running": True}

    # Start WebSocket client in a background asyncio task
    websocket_task = asyncio.create_task(create_websocket_client_task(app_state)())

    yield  # Yield control to FastAPI for its lifespan

    # On shutdown, clean up
    app_state["running"] = False
    await websocket_task  # Wait for the WebSocket task to complete
    print("WebSocket client shutdown")



# Create the FastAPI app with lifespan
app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)

